# Blog post content overlapping with sidebar in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using canard theme in wordpress,when i am opening the blog post then it appear like this http://blog.educroc.com/2016/05/13/5-tricks-student-tries-copy-exam/,i think there is problem with css.

Comment: This is how the text actually looks We&nbsp;as&nbsp;students&nbsp;know&nbsp;how&nbsp;to&nbsp;write&nbsp;an&nbsp;exam&nbsp;but&nbsp;at&nbsp;the&nbsp;same&nbsp;time&nbsp;it&nbsp;is&nbsp;also&nbsp;a&nbsp;talent&nbsp;to&nbsp;copy&nbsp;in&nbsp;an&nbsp;exam. 

The &nbsp; stops the html to wrap the paragraph and that is the reason you experience text overflow.

Comment: yes,what's the solution

Comment: Have you copied the content from any where or have you manually typed in the editor?

Comment: copied the content from ms word doc

Comment: Ok. Copy the content again and paste it in the text tab of editor (not the visual tab)

Comment: Or copy the content from word doc and paste it in notepad. Then copy the content from notepad and paste it in editor

Comment: wow,that soved the problem, thankyou

Comment: I have written an answer, please mark that as right answer so that I get some points. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the content again and paste it in the text tab of editor (not the visual tab)

OR

copy the content from word doc and paste it in notepad. Then copy the content from notepad and paste it in editor